# ExtUtils::MakeMaker: how do I specify a binary executable prerequisite for test and/or installation?

Tags: perl, cpan

I am using `ExtUtils::MakeMaker` to create a `Makefile` for a Perl package from a `Makefile.PL`.

The Perl package (and the tests) are dependent on an executable that the Perl package calls via Perl's `system()`.

Is there any way that I can specify the executable as a prerequisite with `ExtUtils::MakeMaker`.

Comment: As a workaround you can always add a `00dependencies.t` test that fails if the executable isn't there. It will do more work until it gets there, but it will successfully hinder installation.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line anywhere in `Makefile.PL`:

```
system("$executable", "--version") == 0 or die "$executable: $?";
```

You may want to search `$executable` also in other locations than `$PATH` and maybe want better diagnostics on errors but this is essentially what you should do.  For [libintl-perl](https://github.com/gflohr/libintl-perl) I even compile and link C code inside `Makefile.PL`.

Unfortunately, you cannot easily port that technique to `Module::Build` and for the same reason you cannot use it with `Dist::Zilla` or similar build tools.